# How to add an article with size to the card, if the seller isn't CDISCOUNT (0)

Tags: api

I am currently facing a problem with my application, we use the cdiscount api, and to add a product to the card, if this product have an sizeId and the seller in'st CDISCOUNT  it will generate a 500 error.

How can i fixed that ?

thank you for your help.